# “Unmet dependencies. bluez : Conflicts_ bluez-alsa:i386 but 4.98-2ubuntu7 is to be installed”

Tags: apt, package-management, bluez

On my laptop i am using linux mint 18.3 with kernel 4.15.
I get the following error when unsing apt update and apt upgrade.

> Reading package lists... Done
>   Building dependency tree
>   Reading state information... Done
>   Calculating upgrade... Done
>   Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
>   requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
>   distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
>   or been moved out of Incoming.
>   The following information may help to resolve the situation:
>
> The following packages have unmet dependencies:
>   bluez : Conflicts: bluez-alsa:i386 but 4.98-2ubuntu7 is to be installed
>   E: Broken packages

I tried purging an reinstalling bluez with no success.
The way to temporarly fix this problem was by holding back the
"bluez.alsa:i386"-package, because this error would also prevent all
other packages from upgrading.

Using `dkpg --status bluez | grep '^Version:'` tells me that i am
using
`Version: 5.37-0ubuntu5.1` of bluez.

Output of `apt policy bluez bluez-alsa bluez-alsa:i386` :

> bluez:
>     Installed: 5.37-0ubuntu5.1
>     Candidate: 5.37-0ubuntu5.1
>     Version table:
>    *** 5.37-0ubuntu5.1 500
>           500 http://mirror.netcologne.de/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 Packages
>           500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 Packages
>           100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
>        5.37-0ubuntu5 500
>           500 http://mirror.netcologne.de/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
>        4.98-2ubuntu7 500
>           500 ftp://ftp.rz.uni-kiel.de/pub2/linux/ubuntu precise/main amd64   Packages
>
> bluez-alsa:
>     Installed: (none)
>     Candidate: 4.98-2ubuntu7
>     Version table:
>        4.98-2ubuntu7 500
>           500 ftp://ftp.rz.uni-kiel.de/pub2/linux/ubuntu precise/main amd64   Packages
>
> bluez-alsa:i386:
>     Installed: (none)
>     Candidate: 4.98-2ubuntu7
>     Version table:
>        4.98-2ubuntu7 500
>           500 ftp://ftp.rz.uni-kiel.de/pub2/linux/ubuntu precise/main i386 Packages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`bluez-alsa` is no longer relevant, and was removed in version 5.5 of the `bluez` source package (in 2013); you should remove it:

```
sudo apt purge bluez-alsa bluez-alsa:i386
```

You should also disable the Ubuntu Precise repositories:

```
sudo sed -i 's/.*precise.*/#&/g' /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*.list
```